# Grid with data table attached to each polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, visualisation, grids-graticules

I'm trying to wrap my head around a request a colleague gave for some data visualization.

She is performing field observations and for every observation, she is assigning a grid # that corresponds to a pre-existing grid I've created with Alpha/Numeric (row/column) ID's for each grid polygon.

Her question was if it is possible to take the data table she is creating, and attach it to the grid work, so that when she clicks on for instance grid polygon G5, it will pull up the table and show all observations that have the grid ID attribute of G5.

using ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.2

Comment: You could look at [joining the data](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) if the id of the grid and table match.

Comment: You can use relate or simply add attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option without going to deep in creating a custom script or add-in:

**Use ModelBuilder:**

- Use [Feature Set](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ArcGISDesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_using_Feature_Set_and_Record_Set/002w00000023000000/) to interactively select grid feature, **make model parameter*
- Use [Select Layer by Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm) with Grid polygon as input feature and feature set as selecting features input
- Use [Iterators -> Field Value](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-field-value.htm) to get selected grid ID from the result layer from the select layer by location tool
- Use [Select Layer by Attribute](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) with "Value" variable from step above to select all table records for matching grid ID (this is a concept called in-line variable substitution)
- Use [Copy Rows](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-rows.htm) tool to export all selected table records and export to standalone table (set geoprocessing results to add layer/table into map)

Comment: See the difficulty is that the table of observations doesn't have points or x,y locations. Just a field titled Grid, and the Alpha Numeric grid ID associated with where that observation was made. So I have a table that ultimately has no spatial reference other than what grid each observation was made at. And a shp file of the grid that it is referencing. They want it, so when they click on a specific grid polygon, a table pops up showing the observations recorded in that grid. If there was x,y's attached to each observation, this would be a walk in the park.

Comment: @NAlexandrou, updated my answer per your situation